# Spring boot Data-JPA e JSF Java Config

Tags: java, jsf, spring, spring-boot

estou configurando um projeto usando o Spring boot para ioc e Data-Jpa junto com JSF contudo estou com um probleminha no `@Autowired` meu DAO não esta carregando.

Alguém sabe fazer essa configuração e onde posso estar errando?

Segue minha configuração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Classe ApplicationConfig

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ApplicationConfig.class);
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
    FacesServlet servlet = new FacesServlet();
    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "*.xhtml");
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
}
```

Classe loginMbController

```
@ManagedBean(name = "login")
@Component
public class LoginMBController {

@Autowired
private CustomerDao customerDao;

public void test() {
    System.out.println("Hello");
    System.out.println(customerDao);
}
}
```

O customerDao

```
public interface CustomerDao extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{

}
```

O application.properties

```
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

# Datasource
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:jboss/datasources/mysqlDS
```

Login.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<H2>
    <h:outputText value="Login Page" />
</H2>
<h:form>
    <p:button value="ok" onclick="#{login.test()}" />
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

e meu web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>CarlosSnackBar</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

quando eu clico no botão "ok" no console aparece "hello null"

Comment: A injeção funciona em algum outro componente? Já tentou incluir *base package* ou *base package class* no *component scan* para certificar que o DAO esteja no contexto? Outro possível motivo é o MB estar apenas no contexto JSF, e não no Spring

Comment: Opa vlw Bruno, sim eu vou precisar injetar outros componentes e eu tentei colocar explicito no @componentScan o base package mas deu o mesmo problema. e como assim o MB não esta no contexto Spring?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que anotar seu DAO como um Repositorio do Spring Data.

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerDao extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>{

}
```